# Matching key words in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

m trying to match key word but not exactly, something relevant, i use sql LIKE with wilcard %% something like  `'%mens, shoe%'`, will match every data with either men, mens shoe or even both, but the problem is if a user uses an  apostrophe sign like this `'%men\'s, shoe%'`, this will only match record having men's shoe or having men's with apostrophe and will not match men or mens is there a way i can make input with apostrophe sign match records without apostrophe sign thanks for any help

I'm editing my question and adding the SQL statement how it looks like

```
 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.product_id,p.title,p.price,p.unit_sold,p.slug,p.discount,p.free_shipping,free_return,
                p.profile_img,p.store_name,p.item_number,
                (
                    (-- Title score
                    if (title LIKE '%men\'s, shoe%',6,0) + if (title LIKE '%men\'s%',5,0) + if (title LIKE '%shoe%',5,0)
                    )+
                    (-- description
                    if (description LIKE '%men\'s, shoe%',5,0) + if (description LIKE '%men\'s%',4,0) + if (description LIKE '%shoe%',4,0) 
                    )+
                    (-- item number
                    if (item_number = 'men\'s, shoe',4,0) + if (item_number =  'men\'s',3,0) + if (item_number =  'shoe',3,0) 
                    )+
                    (-- category id
                    if (category_id = 'men\'s, shoe',4,0) + if (category_id = 'men\'s',3,0) + if (category_id = 'shoe',3,0) 
                    )

                ) as relevance
                FROM products p
                WHERE p.is_active = '1'

                HAVING relevance > 0
                ORDER BY  relevance DESC LIMIT 2,2
```

Comment: for better text searching you need to use full text index and use `MATCH .. AGAINST` but still I do not believe MySQL is suitable for complex text searching. My suggestion is Solr or Elasticsearch.

Comment: @ Zamrony P. Juhara, thanks after reading some document online i was thinking of giving Elsaticsearch a try but to be honest i can't fully understand how it works i saves data in indexes which can be compare to database, i have some data in my database already if i decided to use ES does that mean i can't search for those data in mysql database with the help of ES, if it's possible can you share with me a good document to read from to know about how to ahceive this,, thanks

Comment: You can use Elasticsearch as search engine, periodically you import data from Mysql to sync data using logstash. https://qbox.io/blog/migrating-mysql-data-into-elasticsearch-using-logstash

Comment: While best (good ?) results can only be achieved by sophisticated text indices or specialized engines, improvements may come from 1.) concatenating all data columns applying the comparisons on the aggregate, 2.) using [regular expression operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html), 3.) normalizing (not in db-theoretical meaning) the tested data (eg. all lower-case, deleting punctuation, removing grammatical markers).

Answer (score 0):

Your condition should look like:

```
someColumn LIKE '%men''s%' or someColumn LIKE '%men\''s%' or someColumn LIKE '%shoe%'
```

where `someColumn` is column name you are interested in. It will match any occurences like: `men's`, `men\'s`, etc.

Comment: thanks for your reply but in this above condition someColumn LIKE '%men%' or someColumn LIKE '%shoe%' is an apostrophe sign is added to the search word like '%men's%' then a match with not be found for items having men in there title or description

Answer (score 0):

Remove apostrophes before comparing:

```
(-- Title score
 (case when replace(title, '''', '') LIKE '%mens, shoe%' then 16
       when replace(title, '''', '') LIKE '%men%' then 5
       when replace(title, '''', '') LIKE '%shoe%' then 5
       else 0
  end) +
   . . .
```

That said, you might want to look into full text search.  It might be a simpler way to accomplish what you want.